# How can I write a 3 byte unicode character as string literal

Tags: dart

Take for example the codes for [these emoticons](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)

For two-byte codes like Dingbats (2702 - 27B0)

```
'abcd\u2702efg'
```

works fine but for longer codes like `\u1F601` this doesn't work.

```
String.fromCharCode(0x1f601)
```

works though.

```
main() {
  print('abcd\u2702efg');
  print('abcd\u1F601efg');
  print(new String.fromCharCode(0x1f601));
}
```

Try at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/f0fbb858c1a4505e28ce)

Is there a way to write `U+1F601` as a string literal in Dart?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Enclose the character code in curly braces:

```
print('abcd\u{1F601}efg');
```

From §16.5, "Strings", of the [Dart Programming
Language Specification, Second Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-408.pdf):

> Strings support escape sequences for special characters. The escapes are:
>
> - ...
> - \x *HEX DIGIT*<sub>1</sub> *HEX DIGIT*<sub>2</sub>, equivalent to
>     \u{*HEX DIGIT*<sub>1</sub> *HEX DIGIT*<sub>2</sub>}.
> - \u *HEX DIGIT*<sub>1</sub> *HEX DIGIT*<sub>2</sub> *HEX DIGIT*<sub>3</sub> *HEX DIGIT*<sub>4</sub>, equivalent
>     to \u{*HEX DIGIT*<sub>1</sub> *HEX DIGIT*<sub>2</sub> *HEX DIGIT*<sub>3</sub> *HEX DIGIT*<sub>4</sub>}.
> - \u{*HEX DIGIT SEQUENCE*} is the unicode scalar value represented
>     by the *HEX DIGIT SEQUENCE*. It is a compile-time error if the
>     value of the *HEX DIGIT SEQUENCE* is not a valid unicode scalar
>     value.