# How to convert unicode with hex to String in dart / flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, unicode, type-conversion, hex

%u0BB5%u0BA3%u0B95%u0BCD%u0B95%u0BAE%u0BCD

Above is unicode with hex characters string
Need to convert that to readable text
When decoded, the above text will return வணக்கம் meaning welcome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Special characters in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50060648/special-characters-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a hard-coded string, as noted in [Special characters in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72136135/)
 and in [the Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#runes-and-grapheme-clusters), you can use `\u` to specify Unicode code points:

```dart
var welcome = '\u0BB5\u0BA3\u0B95\u0BCD\u0B95\u0BAE\u0BCD';
```

If you are given a string `'%u0BB5%u0BA3%u0B95%u0BCD%u0B95%u0BAE%u0BCD'` and need to convert it *dynamically* at runtime, then you will need to:

1. Split the string into `%uXXXX` components.
2. Parse the `XXXX` portion as a hexadecimal integer to get the code point.
3. Construct a `String` from the code points.

```dart
void main() {
  var s = '%u0BB5%u0BA3%u0B95%u0BCD%u0B95%u0BAE%u0BCD';
  var re = RegExp(r'%u(?<codePoint>[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})');
  var matches = re.allMatches(s);
  var codePoints = [
    for (var match in matches)
      int.parse(match.namedGroup('codePoint')!, radix: 16),
  ];
  var decoded = String.fromCharCodes(codePoints);
  print(decoded); // Prints: வணக்கம்
}
```

### Edit 1

An adjusted version that can handle strings with a mixture of encoded code points and unencoded characters:

```dart
void main() {
  var s = '%u0BB5%u0BA3%u0B95%u0BCD%u0B95%u0BAE%u0BCD'
      ' hello world! '
      '%u0BB5%u0BA3%u0B95%u0BCD%u0B95%u0BAE%u0BCD';
  var re = RegExp(r'(%u(?<codePoint>[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}))|.');
  var matches = re.allMatches(s);
  var codePoints = <int>[];
  for (var match in matches) {
    var codePoint = match.namedGroup('codePoint');
    if (codePoint != null) {
      codePoints.add(int.parse(codePoint, radix: 16));
    } else {
      codePoints += match.group(0)!.runes.toList();
    }
  }
  var decoded = String.fromCharCodes(codePoints);
  print(decoded); // Prints: வணக்கம் hello world! வணக்கம்
}
```

### Edit 2

The versions above assumed that your input would consist only of Unicode code points encoded as `%uHHHH` (where H is a hexadecimal digit) and of raw ASCII characters.  However, your [new version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72195643/) indicates that you actually need to handle a mixture of:

- Unicode code points encoded as `%uHHHH`.
- Raw (unencoded) ASCII characters.
- ASCII characters encoded as a `%HH`.

To handle that third case:

```dart
void main() {
  var s = '%3Cp%3E%3Cb%3E%u0B87%u0BA8%u0BCD%u0BA4%u0BBF%u0BAF%u0BBE%u0BB5%u0BBF%u0BA9%u0BCD%20%u0BAA%u0BC6%u0BB0%u0BC1%u0BAE%u0BCD%u0BAA%u0BBE%u0BA9%u0BCD%u0BAE%u0BC8%u0BAF%u0BBE%u0BA9%20%u0BAE%u0B95%u0BCD%u0B95%u0BB3%u0BCD%20%u0BAA%u0BB4%u0B99%u0BCD%u0B95%u0BBE%u0BB2%u0BA4%u0BCD%u0BA4%u0BBF%u0BB2%u0BBF%u0BB0%u0BC1%u0BA8%u0BCD%u0BA4%u0BC7%20.........%20%u0BAA%u0BCB%u0BA9%u0BCD%u0BB1%u0BC1%20%u0BA4%u0BBE%u0BA9%u0BBF%u0BAF%u0B99%u0BCD%u0B95%u0BB3%u0BC8%20%u0BAE%u0BC1%u0B95%u0BCD%u0B95%u0BBF%u0BAF%20%u0B89%u0BA3%u0BB5%u0BBE%u0B95%u0BAA%u0BCD%20%u0BAA%u0BAF%u0BA9%u0BCD%u0BAA%u0B9F%u0BC1%u0BA4%u0BCD%u0BA4%u0BBF%u0BA9%u0BB0%u0BCD.%3C/b%3E%0A%3Col%20type%3D%22I%22%20style%3D%22font-weight%3Abold%3B%22%3E%0A%3Cli%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%22font-weight%3Anormal%3B%22%3E%20%u0B85%u0BB0%u0BBF%u0B9A%u0BBF%3C/span%3E%3C/li%3E%0A%3Cli%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%22font-weight%3Anormal%3B%22%3E%20%u0B95%u0BC7%u0BB4%u0BCD%u0BB5%u0BB0%u0B95%u0BC1%20%3C/span%3E%3C/li%3E%0A%3Cli%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%22font-weight%3Anormal%3B%22%3E%20%u0B93%u0B9F%u0BCD%u0BB8%u0BCD%3C/span%3E%3C/li%3E%0A%3Cli%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%22font-weight%3Anormal%3B%22%3E%20%u0BAA%u0BB0%u0BC1%u0BAA%u0BCD%u0BAA%u0BC1%3C/span%3E%3C/li%3E%3C/ol%3E%3C/p%3E';
  var re = RegExp(
    r'(%(?<asciiValue>[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))'
    r'|(%u(?<codePoint>[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}))'
    r'|.',
  );
  var matches = re.allMatches(s);
  var codePoints = <int>[];
  for (var match in matches) {
    var codePoint = match.namedGroup('asciiValue') ?? match.namedGroup('codePoint');
    if (codePoint != null) {
      codePoints.add(int.parse(codePoint, radix: 16));
    } else {
      codePoints += match.group(0)!.runes.toList();
    }
  }
  var decoded = String.fromCharCodes(codePoints);
  print(decoded);
}
```

which prints:

```
<p><b>இந்தியாவின் பெரும்பான்மையான மக்கள் பழங்காலத்திலிருந்தே ......... போன்று தானியங்களை முக்கிய உணவாகப் பயன்படுத்தினர்.</b>
<ol type="I" style="font-weight:bold;">
<li><span style="font-weight:normal;"> அரிசி</span></li>
<li><span style="font-weight:normal;"> கேழ்வரகு </span></li>
<li><span style="font-weight:normal;"> ஓட்ஸ்</span></li>
<li><span style="font-weight:normal;"> பருப்பு</span></li></ol></p>
```

There are packages that can render HTML (e.g. [`package:flutter_html`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) and probably various others).  Otherwise I'm going to consider dealing with the HTML to be outside the scope of this answer, and that would deserve its own question anyway.