# Dart readAsStringSync not reading lines containing a special character (a dot/full stop)

Tags: dart, dart-io

I am writing a data export/import feature in my application.  The output is written as text to a csv file and this appears to be working ok, but the data import is skipping some of the exported lines (the "statistic" data in the output csv file below) and I can’t understand why this is happening.

So you can see how the file is built, the export routine looks like this:

```
//
// Default to read files from the documents director
final directory =
    await ExternalPath.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExternalPath.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
//
// Build filename
String filename = 'frequentBackup';
filename = filename + DateTime.now().year.toString();
filename =
    filename + DateTime.now().month.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
filename =
   filename + DateTime.now().day.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
filename = '$filename.csv';
String fullname = '$directory/$filename'; // Add path
//
// Build output and save to disk
try {
  //
  // Export Instruments
  File(fullname).writeAsStringSync(exportInstruments(),
      mode: FileMode.write, flush: true);
  //
  // Export Range Names
  File(fullname).writeAsStringSync(exportRanges(),
      mode: FileMode.append, flush: true);
  //
  // Export Frequencies
  File(fullname).writeAsStringSync(exportFrequencies(),
      mode: FileMode.append, flush: true);
  //
  // Export FrequencySort
  File(fullname).writeAsStringSync(
      await exportFrequencySort(database: widget._db),
      mode: FileMode.append,
      flush: true);
  //
  // Export Statistics
  File(fullname).writeAsStringSync(
      await exportStatistics(database: widget._db),
      mode: FileMode.append,
      flush: true);
  //
  // Export AppSettings
  await File(fullname).writeAsString(exportAppSettings(),
      mode: FileMode.append, flush: true);
  //
  // Notify user that the export is complete
  String message = 'Export to $filename complete.';
  showSnackBar(message: message);
```

The individual functions to create the export rows look like this:

Instrument Data:

```
String exportInstruments() {
  String output = '';
  Map<int, String> instruments = Instruments.data();

  instruments.forEach((id, name) {
    output += 'instrument,';
    output += 'id:$id,';
    output += 'name:$name\n';
  });
  return output;
}
```

Range Data:

```
String exportRanges() {
  String output = '';
  Map<int, String> ranges = Ranges.data();

  ranges.forEach((id, name) {
    output += 'range name,';
    output += 'id:$id,';
    output += 'name:$name\n';
  });
  return output;
}
```

Frequency Data:

```
String exportFrequencies() {
  String output = '';
  List<Record> frequencies = Frequencies.master();

  for (Record r in frequencies) {
    output += 'frequency,';
    output += 'fid:${r.id},';
    output += 'iid:${r.instrumentID},';
    output += 'iname:${r.instrument},';
    output += 'rid:${r.rangeNameID},';
    output += 'rname:${r.rangeName},';
    output += 'rtype:${r.rangeType},';
    output += 'fstart:${r.freqStart},';
    output += 'fend:${r.freqEnd},';
    output += 'fundamental:${r.fundamental},';
    output += 'audiofile:${r.audioFile},';
    output += 'audiopath:${r.audioPath} \n';
  }
  return output;
}
```

Frequency Sort Data:

```
Future<String> exportFrequencySort({required MyDatabase database}) async {
  String output = '';

  // Get statistics records from the database (Future)
  await DataFrequencies.getSortOrder(db: database).then((order) {
    order.forEach((position, fid) {
      output += 'frequencyorder,';
      output += 'position:$position,';
      output += 'fid:$fid\n';
    });
  });

  return output;
}
```

Statistic Data:

```
Future<String> exportStatistics({required MyDatabase database}) async {
  String output = '';

  // Get statistics records from the database (Future)
  await DataStatistics.getAllStatistics(db: database).then((statistics) {
    for (StatRecord s in statistics) {
      output += 'statistic,';
      output += 'type:${s.type.toString()},';
      output += 'fid:${s.id},';
      output += 'iid:${s.iid},';
      output += 'rid:${s.rid},';
      output += 'presented:${s.presented},';
      output += 'correct:${s.correct}\n';
    }
  });
  return output;
}
```

App Setting Data:

```
String exportAppSettings() {
  String output = '';
  Map<String, dynamic> settings = Settings.getAllSettings();

  settings.forEach((name, setting) {
    output += 'setting,';
    output += 'name:$name,';
    output += 'setting:$setting\n';
  });
  return output;
}
```

The output csv file produced by these functions looks like this:

```
instrument,id:1,name:banjo 
instrument,id:2,name:piano
instrument,id:3,name:xylophone 
range name,id:1,name:crump
range name,id:2,name:kapow
range name,id:3,name:whump
frequency,fid:1,iid:1,iname:banjo ,rid:1,rname:crump,rtype:R,fstart:30,fend:60,fundamental:1,audiofile:,audiopath: 
frequency,fid:2,iid:1,iname:banjo ,rid:2,rname:kapow,rtype:R,fstart:100,fend:250,fundamental:0,audiofile:,audiopath: 
frequency,fid:3,iid:1,iname:banjo ,rid:3,rname:whump,rtype:R,fstart:1000,fend:2000,fundamental:0,audiofile:,audiopath: 
frequency,fid:4,iid:2,iname:piano,rid:1,rname:crump,rtype:R,fstart:1000,fend:1500,fundamental:0,audiofile:,audiopath: 
frequency,fid:5,iid:2,iname:piano,rid:2,rname:kapow,rtype:R,fstart:2000,fend:3000,fundamental:1,audiofile:,audiopath: 
frequency,fid:6,iid:2,iname:piano,rid:3,rname:whump,rtype:R,fstart:4000,fend:5000,fundamental:0,audiofile:,audiopath: 
frequencyorder,position:0,fid:1
frequencyorder,position:1,fid:2
frequencyorder,position:2,fid:3
frequencyorder,position:3,fid:4
frequencyorder,position:4,fid:5
frequencyorder,position:5,fid:6
statistic,type:FlashType.frequency,fid:1,iid:1,rid:1,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.frequency,fid:2,iid:1,rid:2,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.frequency,fid:3,iid:1,rid:3,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.frequency,fid:4,iid:2,rid:1,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.frequency,fid:5,iid:2,rid:2,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.frequency,fid:6,iid:2,rid:3,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.ranges,fid:1,iid:1,rid:1,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.ranges,fid:2,iid:1,rid:2,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.ranges,fid:3,iid:1,rid:3,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.ranges,fid:4,iid:2,rid:1,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.ranges,fid:5,iid:2,rid:2,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.ranges,fid:6,iid:2,rid:3,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.fundamentals,fid:1,iid:1,rid:1,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.fundamentals,fid:2,iid:1,rid:2,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.fundamentals,fid:3,iid:1,rid:3,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.fundamentals,fid:4,iid:2,rid:1,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.fundamentals,fid:5,iid:2,rid:2,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.fundamentals,fid:6,iid:2,rid:3,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.sounds,fid:1,iid:1,rid:1,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.sounds,fid:2,iid:1,rid:2,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.sounds,fid:3,iid:1,rid:3,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.sounds,fid:4,iid:2,rid:1,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.sounds,fid:5,iid:2,rid:2,presented:0,correct:0
statistic,type:FlashType.sounds,fid:6,iid:2,rid:3,presented:0,correct:0
setting,name:colourOneEnabled,setting:false
setting,name:colourOne,setting:#fffff59d
setting,name:colourTwoEnabled,setting:false
setting,name:colourTwo,setting:#ff9dffb1
setting,name:fontColourEnabled,setting:false
setting,name:fontColour,setting:#ff000000
setting,name:fundamentalColourEnabled,setting:false
setting,name:fundamentalColour,setting:#ff4caf50
setting,name:disabledColourEnabled,setting:false
setting,name:disabledColour,setting:#ff9e9e9e
setting,name:themeMode,setting:ThemeMode.dark
setting,name:leftHanded,setting:false
```

The import routine that reads this file uses `readAsStringSync` (I have the same issue if I use `readAsLinesSync`) as follows:

```
String fullName = result.files.first.path as String;
dynamic temp = File(fullName).readAsStringSync();
print('$temp');
```

The debug console output looks like this:

```
I/flutter ( 6499): instrument,id:1,name:banjo 
I/flutter ( 6499): instrument,id:2,name:piano 
I/flutter ( 6499): instrument,id:3,name:xylophone 
I/flutter ( 6499): range name,id:1,name:crump 
I/flutter ( 6499): range name,id:2,name:kapow 
I/flutter ( 6499): range name,id:3,name:whump 
I/flutter ( 6499): frequency,fid:1,iid:1,iname:banjo ,rid:1,rname:crump,rtype:R,fstart:30,fend:60,fundamental:1,audiofile:,audiopath: 
I/flutter ( 6499): frequency,fid:2,iid:1,iname:banjo ,rid:2,rname:kapow,rtype:R,fstart:100,fend:250,fundamental:0,audiofile:,audiopath: 
I/flutter ( 6499): frequency,fid:3,iid:1,iname:banjo ,rid:3,rname:whump,rtype:R,fstart:1000,fend:2000,fundamental:0,audiofile:,audiopath: 
I/flutter ( 6499): frequency,fid:4,iid:2,iname:piano,rid:1,rname:crump,rtype:R,fstart:1000,fend:1500,fundamental:0,audiofile:,audiopath: 
I/flutter ( 6499): frequency,fid:5,iid:2,iname:piano,rid:2,rname:kapow,rtype:R,fstart:2000,fend:3000,fundamental:1,audiofile:,audiopath: 
I/flutter ( 6499): frequency,fid:6,iid:2,iname:piano,rid:3,rname:whump,rtype:R,fstart:4000,fend:5000,fundamental:0,audiofile:,audiopath: 
I/flutter ( 6499): frequencyorder,position:0,fid:1 
I/flutter ( 6499): frequencyorder,position:1,fid:2 
I/flutter ( 6499): frequencyorder,position:2,fid:3 
I/flutter ( 6499): frequencyorder,position:3,fid:4 
I/flutter ( 6499): frequencyorder,position:4,fid:5 
I/flutter ( 6499): frequencyorder,position:5,fid:6 
I/flutter ( 6499): setting,name:colourOneEnabled,setting:false 
I/flutter ( 6499): setting,name:colourOne,setting:#fffff59d 
I/flutter ( 6499): setting,name:colourTwoEnabled,setting:false 
I/flutter ( 6499): setting,name:colourTwo,setting:#ff9dffb1 
I/flutter ( 6499): setting,name:fontColourEnabled,setting:false 
I/flutter ( 6499): setting,name:fontColour,setting:#ff000000 
I/flutter ( 6499): setting,name:fundamentalColourEnabled,setting:false 
I/flutter ( 6499): setting,name:fundamentalColour,setting:#ff4caf50 
I/flutter ( 6499): setting,name:disabledColourEnabled,setting:false 
I/flutter ( 6499): setting,name:disabledColour,setting:#ff9e9e9e 
I/flutter ( 6499): setting,name:themeMode,setting:ThemeMode.system 
I/flutter ( 6499): setting,name:leftHanded,setting:false
```

Note the missing “statistic” lines between the "frequencyorder" and "setting" lines.

I am running Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.11, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1555], locale en-GB).

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: try using debugPrint. Standard android logcat drops part of string if the data is too long.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That hasn't worked.  If you look at the csv file and the result of the import, the readAsStringSync is losing a section in the middle of the file and not at the end.  The file is 54 lines long and the read is losing lines 19-42.  All of these lines start with "statistic", which makes me think there is something wrong with that output.  I cant see any odd characters in the file that would make it different to the other rows... other than the dot in "FlashType.sounds", but I cant see why that would be an issue.

Comment: Having said that... I just hardcoded the export to remove the dot in "FlashType.sounds" and now the lines are showing up in the import so it is the dot that is causing the problem.  Is this treated as a special character?  And if so, how do I get around this?  I am exporting an enum as a String and what to be able to re-import this and convert back to an enum.

Comment: I tried changing the export to wrap Flashtype.sounds in quotes and then reimported it.  That works, except that the import removes the dot from the value as follows: ```I/flutter ( 9149): statistic,type:FlashTypesounds,fid:1,iid:1,rid:1,presented:0,correct:0```.  I have tried escaping the dot (\.) and replacing with unicode (\u002e).  The import sees the lines, but still removes the dot.  How do I preserve the dot?

Comment: Ignore the last comment.  The unicode conversion did work, but I had to clear the cache on the app before importing the file because it was importing an older cached version of the file and not the newly exported version (I am over-writing the same file each time so perhaps it just caches on file name?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the post here: [Special characters in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50060648/special-characters-in-flutter), the solution is to convert the dot to unicode and then export the String.  When this is read by readAsString or readAsLines, the unicode is converted back to a dot automatically.  My export code now looks like this:

```
    Future<String> exportStatistics({required MyDatabase database}) async {
      String output = '';

      // Get statistics records from the database (Future)
      await DataStatistics.getAllStatistics(db: database).then((statistics) {
        for (StatRecord s in statistics) {
          output += 'statistic,';
          dynamic temp = s.type.toString().replaceAll('.', '\u002e');
          output += 'type:$temp,';
          output += 'fid:${s.id},';
          output += 'iid:${s.iid},';
          output += 'rid:${s.rid},';
          output += 'presented:${s.presented},';
          output += 'correct:${s.correct}\n';
        }
      });
      return output;
    }
```

This wasn't immediately obvious in testing because I have also learned that, on my setup at least, when I am testing the app on a physically attached device I needed to clear the cache on the app before importing the new file.  If I don't do this, then the app seems to be importing a previously cached version of the file even after changing the export routine, restarting the app and re-exporting the data to the export file.  Because of this, it looks like changes haven't worked when they have.